# How do you get an id of an instanced object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create list-like objects that get instanced into the HTML file after created. However, I want it to be removed with delete button but I don't know how to get custom a custom id and delete the parent node. What should I do? I have been stuck with this for hours ;(

code for javascript:

```
var listnum = 0;
var butadd = 250;
var numadd = 360; 

var started = false;

var id_arr = []

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' ,addList, false);
document.addEventListener('OnClick' ,delList, false);

function addList()
{
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function()
    {   

        if (started == false){
            started = true;
        }

        var new_list = document.createElement('DIV');
        new_list.className = "list";
        var newlistid = String('newList' + listnum);
        new_list.id = newlistid;

        //let script =    document.createElement('script');
        //script.src = '/listitem.js';
      //document.getElementById(newlistid).appendChild(script);

        var delete_list = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        delete_list.className = "delList";
        //delete_list.id = listnum;
        delete_list.id = 'deletebutton';

        listnum++;
        id_arr.push(listnum);
        extendCont();

        document.getElementById('Lcontainer').appendChild(new_list);
        document.getElementById(newlistid).appendChild(delete_list);
    }, false);
}


function extendCont(){
    if (listnum >= 5)
    {
       document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", 'height: '+numadd+'px');
       document.getElementById('button').setAttribute("style", "top:"+ butadd + 'px');
        numadd += 65;
        butadd += 65;
    }
}


function delList(oObject)
{   
    //delete list here
}
```

Comment: `delete_list.onclick = function () { document.getElementById('Lcontainer').removeChild(this.parent); };`

Comment: @ChrisG I tried onclick before but it does not seem to be working

Comment: Try creating a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, it's `this.parentNode`.

Comment: I put all the code you commented in the delList function. Sorry I am new to the Javascript and it's very confusing

Comment: No, that line is supposed to go after `delete_list.id = 'deletebutton';` for instance.